# ionic 2 for browser platform is not working

Tags: ionic2

I want to create an app which is able to run in mobile phone and also in browser (of course no device dependency functions). Here are the steps:

> ionic start --v2 demo blank
>
> cd demo
>
> ionic platform add browser
>
> ionic build browser
>
> cd platforms/browser
>
> php -S localhost:8000

Then open localhost:8000 in browser.

[image]

I looked through the ionicframework document. There is nothing about **platform browser**. Can anybody advise how I can run my app in browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the browser platform, just run `ionic serve`:

```
ionic start --v2 demo blank

cd demo

ionic serve
```

Further information can be found [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/serve/).

Comment: This is not what I want because I only want to deploy my web app to other servers for example php server which is not possible to run node.

Comment: You only need to run `ionic serve` during development, so that each time you modify something, that change will be also reflected in the www folder. In order to deploy the web app, in your www folder you'll find that the web app is just an `index..html` file with an `asset` and `build` folders. Your server just need to load that index.html and that should be it.

Comment: I know this. My issue is the page is not loaded probably because of the cordova not working in browser. I'd like to know how to make my code support mobile and browser at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run browser platform, then `cd platforms/browser/www` instead of `cd platforms/browser`, and run local server from there.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation **[ionic2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/platform/)**, its clear that the platform can either be ios or android as shown below screenshot.

[image]

So, when you want to render it in a browser, you can simply use

```
ionic serve
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following code at the root of the project and then the web-browser based version will be generated at `/www/` folder including the sub-directories such as `assets`, `build` & `index.html` which is the main point of entry for the web app.

If you wanna have the app packaged as a staging or production bundle, the following command can be used, which will again generate the prod build at the same `/www/`location.

```
npm run ionic:build --prod
```